# How to avoid hot partitions and still provide necessary access patterns

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to design a DynamoDB table for a multisite CMS.  I'm having a difficult time defining primary, partition, and sort keys to distribute data across partitions and allow me to query.

Users will only be able to access posts in their domain.  Some domains will have many more posts than others. Since all of the queries will need to limit results based on domain, how can I spread data evenly across partitions (as I understand, you can't query across partitions)?

My initial thought was to use a composite Partition Key and `begins-with` to query:

`Domain | Post-Type | Post-Year | Post-Month | Post-Day | slug`

`example.com / blog / 2019 / 09 / 30 / post-slug`

The Sort Key would be the date I guess.

When this partition key is hashed, will it distribute well?  Most queries will be for a particular domain and post-type ordered by date. Is there a better way to go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NoSQL schema depends on what queries you intend to do (as opposite to SQL where to try to normalise it as much as possible).

So if your query will be "get all posts from a particular domain", then the simplest approach would be to have "domain" as an index hash key (with timestamp as sort key). As you mentioned, this will cause hot partitions so we need to split "domain" up a bit, like this composite key "domain-year-month". This way we make sure a partition will not be more than 10GB (current DynamoDB limit). Of course, if we will have more data, we need to extend it even more: "domain-year-dayOfYear" and so on.

So your way of thinking is mostly correct, but I wouldn't use "begins-with". Just because you usually don't fetch such a large amount of data that is spread across multiple partitions (make your partitions larger if so).